# How to get if a specific user is online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've got some code which should send in the current status of a user if they switched to online, but the problem is that it sends the message twice AND that I can't check who the user who changed their status is. I just want it to check IF the user who changed their status is a person with a specific ID and IF their status changed to "online"

```js
bot.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
 console.log(newMember.presence.status + ' ' + oldMember.presence.status);
 if (newMember.presence.status == 'online') {
  if (!(oldMember == newMember)) {
   bot.channels
    .get('622437397891907586')
    .send(newMember.presence.status.toString());
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldGuildMember, newGuildMember) => {
    if (oldGuildMember.id !== "YOURID") return false; // Checking if the GuildMember is a specific user.

    if (oldGuildMember.presence.status !== newGuildMember.presence.status) { // Checking if the Presence is the same.
        if (newGuildMember.presence.status == "online") { // Checking if the GuildMember is online.
            const Channel = client.channels.get("CHANNELID");
            if (!Channel) return console.error("Invalid channel.");
            if (newGuildMember.guild.id !== Channel.guild.id) return false; // Making sure the Message gets sent once.

            Channel.send(`${newGuildMember.user.tag} is now online!`);
        };
    };
});
```